# Brew Install Octave - Permission Denied

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I am having a hard time running `brew install octave` on my machine.

Here is the specific error I am getting since it fails on the package `icu4c`:

```
...
==> Installing octave dependency: icu4c
==> Pouring icu4c-67.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: Permission denied
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/LICENSE: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1/bin: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/bin/makeconv: No such file or directory
....
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/config: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1/mkinstalldirs: No such file or directory
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu/67.1: No such file or directory
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share/icu: No such file or directory
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1/share: No such file or directory
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: No such file or directory
cp: /var/folders/k4/xg60pppx3392pm_9tjyy35gc0000gn/T/d20200815-50984-1k6mia6/icu4c/./67.1: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/./67.1: Permission denied
cp: utimes: /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/.: Operation not permitted

Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
```

From what I'm seeing online, I see a lot of people saying to change ownership of the specific folder - which I tried.

I have checked the ownership of the folder, and it's set to my user. Postgres is also using the icu4c.

I'm not sure where to go from here, because I read that it would give an error like this if you have the folder set to root permission; so I'm not sure why this error is getting kicked back if I already changed the ownership.

Comment: What is the result of `cd /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error, the folder `icu4c/67.1` might not exist. Therefore you have to create it manually by:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
```

and then change the ownership to your current user:

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
```

Comment: when I did this, I received a different error after running `brew install octave` again. This time it said could not remove /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1 so do so manually. Did that, then tried the run the install again. Took me back to my first error

Comment: `Error: Could not remove 67.1 keg! Do so manually: sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1`

Comment: I have one more suggestion. I assume after, you have created the directory you did not change the ownership, am I wrong? Could you please try `sudo chown $USER /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1`

Comment: I definitely thought I changed the ownership, but I don't think I did. Still running now, but it looks like it passed through the initial roadblock so this response has solved my question - thank you!!

Comment: @Madison: you probably need to change ownership and permissions of `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c`. It would probably be a good idea to verify that `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/Cellar` are also both owned by your regular user and not root.

Comment: @CrisLuengo An answer has already been accepted and the issue is fixed

Comment: @MadisonLeopold: I saw that. I was hoping to help you fix any possible underlying issues. You should not have to worry about ownership and permissions with Homebrew. You have a configuration problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I see - I appreciate it so much!

Answer (score -1):

try to: `sudo brew cask install octave` .

Comment: this command does not work - it states it is no longer supported and regardless, it's extremely dangerous (stated in error)

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.